# Adding JS File with HTML Code

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to create a .js file and add html code to it. I'm interested in putting my client-side scripting coding into a .js file. Then I can put that file in another location to call upon it to load the HTML code.

It's all on a desktop computer with no server type of support.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

I would add that to the HEAD section which is the one I think I need. But wondered if it was possible.

Thanks!

Comment: yes, you can have JS generate html. e.g. quick/dirty/simple example: `<script>document.write('<p>Hi mom!</p>');</script>`

Comment: How do I plug the HTML into a .js file though?

Comment: `function foo() { ... code to build html ... }`

Comment: So when I add function foo*( { HTML CODE } on the main page, it works. When I try to add it a .js file, and embed it, I think I'm doing it wrong because it doesn't seem to work quite right.

Comment: well, "doesn't work" is useless information. you wouldn't be here if it was...

Comment: I think you were on to something. Do I need to add <script src="file.js"></script> or also add some additional code to call out the function foo?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a few ways of doing what you're aiming for.

**Raw Javascript**

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.js:

```
document.write('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
```

But you should note that this isn't very comfortable for large HTML as you're mixing HTML into JS.

**Template engines**

A better option could be a template engine, like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).
This allows you to keep your HTML clean and apart from your Javascript.
See this sample:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

content.js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile(this.responseText);
  document.body.innerHTML += template()
};
xhr.open('get', 'template.html');
xhr.send();
```

template.html:

```
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
```

This won't work on your local filesystem, but will work fine via HTTP.

The biggest benefit of the template engine is the ability to fill in dynamic content, for instance:

content.js:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
  var template = Handlebars.compile(this.responseText);
  document.body.innerHTML += template({name: 'World'})
};
xhr.open('get', 'template.html');
xhr.send();
```

The properties in the params of the `template()` call are filled into the corresponding `{{name}}` inside the template.

Comment: In this case, I don't have access to HTTP. It's only run from a desktop

Answer (score -1):

Please check out this code:

```
var type = document.createAttribute("type");
type.value = 'text/javascript';

var src = document.createAttribute("src");
src.value = 'file.js';

var scrpt = document.createElement("script");
scrpt.setAttributeNode(type);
scrpt.setAttributeNode(src);

var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(scrpt);
```